# Create thumbnail from Adobe Illustrator file?

Tags: image-processing

Does anybody know how to create a thumbnail from an Adobe Illustrator file without using Illustrator?  I have a php/linux based application and I'd like to do so.

-Dave

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, Adobe Illustrator saves files as PDF compatible.  Unless the file was saved in a strange way, you should be able to use ImageMagick directly to generate a thumbnail.  For example:

```
convert file.ai -thumbnail 250x250 -unsharp 0x.5  thumbnail.png
```

**Note:** If the file has multiple artboards (which are interpreted as pages as a PDF), it will generate multiple files or, if saved as a GIF, an animated GIF.

Answer (score 0):

If you can save it in PDF, PS, or EPS format you may be able to manipulate it in things like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/).

EDIT:

I think you can actually use ImageMagick's [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) with *.ai files as well.