# Best Thumbnail Tool for Thumbnailing PDFs, PSDs, TIFs and Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

Can anybody recommend a good API/Tool for programmatic image thumbnailing of PDF, PSD, TIF and Adobe Illustrator file types, as well as regular image file types of course, e.g. JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

In c#, psd thumbnail can be created using ImageMagicNet.  But it doesn't seems to work with  Adobe Illustrator file type.  It will be helpful if any one help on this

Answer (score 0):

For Adobe Illustrator [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1678439/152876) may be all you need. Given that this technique also covers PDFs, I would say that ImageMagic covers your list of required file types.